# path of svg stopPropagation() not working

Tags: javascript, svg

```js
const container= document.getElementById("container")
const path = document.getElementById("myPath")

path.onclick = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation() // not working
    console.log("path clicked !")
    }
    
container.onmousedown = (event) => {
    console.log("container clicked !")
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">
<path id="myPath" d="M10 80 Q 95 10 180 80" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" />
</svg>
</div>
```

When I click to `path` not working `event.stopPropagation()`. I just want to run `alert("Path clicked !")`. But running both listeners. Where is problem in this codes ?

Comment: `stopImmediatePropagation` might help, but if I remember correctly, to stop propagation you need to `capture` the event in a parent?

Comment: I need to catch from child that event, so path of svg. I tried `stopImmediatePropagation`, but it did not run :) @somethinghere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stopPropagation()` works okay as it is - it stops the propagation of events of *the same type*, so you need to change the event handlers to either both `onclick` or both `onmousedown`.

```js
const container= document.getElementById("container")
const path = document.getElementById("myPath")

container.onclick = (event) => {
    console.log("container clicked !")
    }

path.onclick = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation()
    console.log("path clicked !")
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">
<path id="myPath" d="M10 80 Q 95 10 180 80" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" />
</svg>
</div>
```